# App Rarely Crash on setContentView

Tags: android

i have a `ListActivity` Intent from another ListActivity, About 1 times to 10 times the program crashes at `Intent` The Activity , when i log that the problem is `setContentView` line

```
public class MessageActivity extends ListActivity {
 private ListView list;

 //...

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
     list = getListView();

  //...

  }
}
```

activity_message XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@id/activity_welcome_l1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
    <include  layout="@layout/header4" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="vertical">

    <include  layout="@layout/footer1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<include  layout="@layout/draver_menu" />
</FrameLayout>
```

RuntimeException :

```
08-23 13:32:26.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.in.ss/ir.in.ss.pages.sms_chat.MessageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1682)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:940)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:211)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    at ir.in.ss.pages.sms_chat.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:108)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1630)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:350)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:343)
    ... 29 more
```

Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private Activity A;
private ListView list;
private LazyAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayout search_layer;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.A = this;
        list = getListView();
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(A, R.layout.list_row, R.layout.layout_one, H.BoxInfo);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ...
        Button search_button = (Button) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_button_search);
        search_layer = (LinearLayout) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_search_layer);
        search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) A.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibe.vibrate(50);
                if (search_layer.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    search_layer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    search_text.requestFocus();

                } else {
                    search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    search_text.setText("");
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });


        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) A.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibe.vibrate(50);
                BoxInfoObject Box = adapter.getItem(position);
                inbox_init QA = new inbox_init(A, adapter, Box);
                inboxQuickAction quickAction = QA.initialize(Box);
                quickAction.show(view);
                return true;
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                BoxInfoObject Box = adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(A, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_POSITION, H.BoxInfo.indexOf(Box) + "");
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_NEW_MESSAGE_OPNS,
                        Box.getOPNs());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_NEW_MESSAGE_PNS,
                        Box.getPNs());
                A.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e3) {
        Log.i("H", "MainActivity.Exception e3******************************");
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.error1) +
                "002" + this.getString(R.string.error2)
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (search_layer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onRestart");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

any suggestion ?

Comment: can you provide stack trace plz?

Comment: @hamiderza please provide the stacktrace

Comment: The error is thrown in MainActivity. Provide its onCreate code.

Comment: Paste your `MainActivity.onBackPressed` method

Comment: The var `search_layer` in the method `onBackPressed()` is not used somethere else in that Activity. Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: Try placing e3.printStackTrace() in your catch phrase after `Log.i("H", "MainActivity.Exception e3******************************");` and the post it here

Comment: do you have `search_layer` in `activity_main` layout file?

Comment: @bhargavg Yes , and the crash is about 1 times to 10 times run

Comment: @hoomi, the Exception e3 not catch , the Exception catch is in MessageActivity and i did post trace of that

Comment: @Hamidreza the stacktrace that you have posted is because your code did not reach `search_layer = (LinearLayout) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_search_layer);` so in onBackPressed() search_layer is null and that is why you get a NullPointerException. You need to figure out why the e3 was thrown

Comment: Thanks @hoomi , I will check that

Comment: @hoomi , i remove the whole search_layer, but the crash Remains, check update of stack trace.

Comment: Well, now you see your error. You try to load something (I guess a picture) that needs more memory than your virtual machine could spend. So shrink your file or check what else needs so much memory. Or increase the memory size.

Comment: @Hamidreza you are getting out of memory exception. How big is your message_bar file?

Comment: not so much file , just a couple icon less than 100 kb , maybe repeated row icon cause that, i will check that, @hoomi give me your comments as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code did not reach `search_layer = (LinearLayout) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_search_layer);` so in `onBackPressed()` search_layer is null and that is why you get a NullPointerException, you need to figure out why the e3 was thrown.
And since you have OutOfMemoryException I am guessing that the images that you are using are quite big. try reduce their size and see if it happens again. Also try avoid using too many overdraws if you can

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use setContentView when you using ListActivity.
if you need that,you should use Activity and use ListView widget in it's layout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Context A;
private ListView list;
private LazyAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayout search_layer;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.A = this;
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, R.layout.layout_one, H.BoxInfo);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ...
    Button search_button = (Button) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_button_search);
    search_layer = (LinearLayout) A.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_search_layer);
    search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) A.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(50);
            if (search_layer.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                search_layer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                search_text.requestFocus();

            } else {
                search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                search_text.setText("");
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });


    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) A.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(50);
            BoxInfoObject Box = adapter.getItem(position);
            inbox_init QA = new inbox_init(A, adapter, Box);
            inboxQuickAction quickAction = QA.initialize(Box);
            quickAction.show(view);
            return true;
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            BoxInfoObject Box = adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(A, MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_POSITION, H.BoxInfo.indexOf(Box) + "");
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_NEW_MESSAGE_OPNS,
                    Box.getOPNs());
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra(MessageActivity.KEY_NEW_MESSAGE_PNS,
                    Box.getPNs());
            A.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

} catch (Exception e3) {
    Log.i("H", "MainActivity.Exception e3******************************");
    Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.error1) +
            "002" + this.getString(R.string.error2)
            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    onBackPressed();
}
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (search_layer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    search_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
}
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
super.onRestart();
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onRestart");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Log.i("H", "MainActivity.onResume");
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks MHP, what should i use

Comment: thanks MHP, i think the other answers give me the clue